# Nonlinear Equation involving a matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-calculus, numerical-optimization

I have a matrix $A$ whose entries are each a function of a variable $\epsilon$, with $\epsilon>0$. This matrix arises from Radial Basis Function (RBF) interpolation, and is symmetric positive-definite.

I will write this as $A(\epsilon)$. My goal is to find a value $\epsilon*$ that sets the condition number of the matrix to a specific target. In other words, if $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$, I need to ensure that $\kappa(A) = \kappa_T$, where $\kappa_T$ is some target condition number. To do this, I numerically solve the equation
\begin{align}
log\left(\frac{\kappa\left(A(\epsilon)\right)}{\kappa_T} \right) = f(\epsilon) =  0. 
\end{align}
for $\epsilon$. In Matlab, I currently do this with the in-built fzero(), which uses the Brent-Dekker method. This method converges pretty slowly; for small dense matrices of size $50 \times 50$, for example, fzero sometimes takes 30+ iterations.

However, it occurred to me that I could possibly do this with Newton's method, if only I could compute the derivative of the above quantity. If $\epsilon$ is a scalar, and $A_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (\epsilon r_{ij})^2}}$, where $r_{ij}$ is some scalar independent of $\epsilon$, how do I compute the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon}$?

I have no idea how to compute the derivative of the condition number of a matrix, since I am not really familiar with matrix calculus. I'd appreciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: I get $$\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial h} = \frac{A_{ij}^3-A_{ij}}{h}$$which can be combined with @hans answer below to fully answer your question.

Comment: Woops! The variable $h$ in my previous comment should be $\epsilon$.

Comment: This is indeed true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Frobenius norm for algebraic convenience, the differential of the norm is easily found 
$$\eqalign{
  \|A\|^2 &= A:A  \cr
  2\,\|A\|\,d\|A\| &= 2\,A:dA  \cr
  d\|A\| &= \frac{A}{\|A\|} : dA  \cr
}$$
where the colon denotes the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).

The differential of the inverse is also easy to determine 
$$\eqalign{
  A\,A^{-1} &= I \cr
  dA\,A^{-1} + A\,dA^{-1} &= 0 \cr
  dA^{-1} &= -A^{-1}\,(dA)\,A^{-1} \cr
}$$

The condition number is 
$$\eqalign{
 \kappa &= \|A^{-1}\|\,\|A\| \cr\cr
}$$
Use these 3 facts to find the differential and gradient of $\kappa$ 
$$\eqalign{
d\kappa &= \|A^{-1}\|\,d\|A\| + \|A\|\,d\|A^{-1}\| \cr
 &= \|A^{-1}\|\,\frac{A}{\|A\|}:dA + \|A\|\,\frac{A^{-1}}{\|A^{-1}\|}:dA^{-1} \cr
 &= \|A^{-1}\|\,\frac{A}{\|A\|}:dA - \|A\|\,\frac{A^{-1}}{\|A^{-1}\|}:A^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1} \cr\cr
 &= \Bigg(\frac{\|A^{-1}\|^2A-\|A\|^2A^{-T}A^{-1}A^{-T}}{\kappa}\Bigg) :dA \cr
}$$
Since $\big(d\kappa=\frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial A}:dA\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial A} &= \frac{\|A^{-1}\|^2A-\|A\|^2A^{-T}A^{-1}A^{-T}}{\kappa} \cr
}$$
Finally, the gradient wrt $\epsilon$ is given by
$$\eqalign{
\frac{d\kappa}{d\epsilon} &= \frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial A} : \frac{\partial A}{\partial\epsilon}\cr
}$$

I'm not sure why you want to complicate your problem by introducing a logarithm, since the following function will also yield the target condition number
$$f(\epsilon) = \kappa(\epsilon) - \kappa_T = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. As to why I was using the log value, the target condition numbers I use are often very large. This way, I figured I would only be working with smaller numbers, less susceptible to numerical errors. However, now that I have Newton's method (thanks to you), I can play around and decide what to do with this. It may very well be that logs are unnecessary.

Comment: I also want to add: that expression for $\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial A}$ simplifies a fair bit when $A = A^T$. Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

[Automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Automatic_differentiation_using_dual_numbers) can be used to (exactly) compute derivatives of any differentiable function that you can calculate. (I don't think you'll find a useful expression using standard analytic methods)

Comment: In case I don't receive any other answers, @Wouter, care to share a source to some reliable AD library for Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: defining $\Delta(A) = (A,A)$, $N(A) = \|A\|$, $\iota(A) = A^{-1}$, $p(x,y) = xy$, $\operatorname{cond}$ is a composition:
$$A\longmapsto(A,A)\longmapsto(A,\iota(A))\longmapsto (N(A),N(\iota(A)))\longmapsto N(A)N(\iota(A)),$$
$$p\circ(N\times N)\circ(Id\times\iota)\circ\Delta.$$
Now apply chain rule. This depends of the concrete norm used and see [differential inverse matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200856/differential-inverse-matrix).

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with your notation. Are you using parenthesis (A,A) to represent inner products, or is that just a vector?

Comment: @vergere6, the ordered pair.